# In Xcode 5, how can I use comment ///

Tags: objective-c, xcode, comments, xcode5

When I use comment like this

```
/* style 1 */
NSMutableArray *wayPoints;   ///Player's wayPoints ARRAY
CGPoint        velocity;     ///Player's current speed and direction
```

Code documentation doesn't work.
But when I code like this.

```
/* style 2 */
///Player's wayPoints ARRAY
NSMutableArray *wayPoints;
///Player's current speed and direction
CGPoint        velocity;
```

It works.
But it doesn't looks clear.

So how can I use like `/* style 1 */`

Comment: You can use the [VVDocumenter-Xcode](https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode) plugin to automate writing the correct comments whenever you type `///`. Easiest would be to install it via [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although both styles are appropriate...
It is better to use /* Style 1 */ for variable declarations or assignments, where line of code is small, and use /* style 2 */ for commenting methods or functions, where line of code is large.

Comment: For me /* Style 1 */ and /* Style 2 */ both are working in xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

yes use this /* your code for comment  */ for multi line comment,
use // this for single line comment and both are working for me in xcode 5